# how can i transfer downloaded music from the sd card to the internal storage

Tags: settings, storage, file-transfer

The music I download gets stored into my SD card. How do I get it to store into my phone's internal storage?

Comment: What music app are you using? Google Play Music has an option in settings where to save the music, selecting one will move all music saved there. If they are downloaded elsewhere the app may have a setting, otherwise a file manager as mentioned below.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to move files with the built in file manager.  On my Samsung S3 phone, it's called "My Files" and looks like a file folder.  The manager has options to copy from SD card to device memory.  If you don't have a default file manager, you can get one (eg. ES File Explorer) from the play store.